# Inheritance domain classes in Grails

Tags: grails

how can I get Collection of specific Class?

I use inheriance: On Planet live Human. Humans are dividing to Men and Women.

```
class Planet{
   String name
   static hasMany = [ humans : Human ]
}

class Human{
    String name
    static belongsTo = [Planet]
}

class Man extends Human{
     int countOfCar
}

class Woman extends Human{
     int coutOfChildren  
}
```

now a neet to get only Collection of Man or Collection of Woman:

get all humans on planet is simple

```
all = Planet.get(1).humans
```

but what can I get only woman or men?
womenLivedOnMars = Planet.get(1).**getOnlyWoman**
menLivedOnJupiter = Planet.get(2).**getOnlyMan**

Thanks for your help
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option could be:

```
Man.findAllByPlanet(Planet.get(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can do it these ways:

```
class Human{
    String name
    static belongsTo = [planet: Planet]
}


womanLivedOnMars = Woman.findAllByPlanet(Planet.findByName('Mars'))

menLivedOnJupiter = Men.withCriteria {
    planet {
        eq('name','Mars')
    }
}
```